# How to Make HTML Elements in Compact mode VS Code

Tags: html, jquery, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

I tried to format my HTML Selection of HTML Elements in Compact View I tried too many  Visual Studio Extension but none of them working like Ctrl + J and Prettify so on

Here is the example of my code look likes

```
<div class="example">
<div class="section">
<div class="widget">
<div class="title">
<h3 class="title">I am a developer</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I need Like this Below

```
<div class="example"><div class="section">
<div class="widget">
<div class="title"><h3 class="title">I am a developer</h3></div>
</div></div></div>
```

Like above this format there is too much code I need to format with help of any  extension in VS code if possible Suggest me
Any Help is Highly Appreciated

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.minify

Answer (score 0):

it is always good to format your code well using indentation. This helps one identify parent and child elements especially when an element has more than to child elements.

e.g.

```
<div class="example">
    <div class="section">
    <div class="widget">
    <div class="title">
        <h3 class="title">I am a developer</h3>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```